# (Swift) ViewController's UI-elements can not be edited by implemented delegate method

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to update the label in the DetailViewController everytime I selected a tableRow in the MasterViewController. To achieve this, I designed a delegate, which I have in the MasterVC

```
protocol TestTableViewControllerDelegate {
func selectedRow(selectedCar : Car)
}

class TestTableViewController: UITableViewController {
...
var delegate : TestTableViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.delegate = DetailViewController()
```

The delegate works just fine, (it is implemented correctly in the DetailVC), it can pass values from TestTableVC to DetailVC and also correctly do println(), which prints a new Car.model String to the console every time I select a row in the TTVC.
The DetailVC looks like this (shortened):

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController, TestTableViewControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var textLabel: UILabel!

var theCar : Car? {
    didSet(newCar) {
        refreshUI()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    refreshUI()
}

func selectedRow(selectedCar : Car) {
    theCar = selectedCar
    refreshUI()
}

func refreshUI() {
    textLabel?.text = theCar!.model
}

}
```

I can achieve any kind of action with my delegate, expect for refreshing the UI. I have tried numerous ways, this is my latest attempt. Before that, I tried setting the textLabel's text property directly within the delegate method, didn't work. This problem only occurs when working with the UI-elements. I know it has something to do with the view not being loaded yet, but why does my refreshUI() function not work at all?
I am still a beginner, so any tip or help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I've used is to cerate a properly in the delegate and pass the value to it instead of the UI element. When the view loads I update the label's text properly with the value of the delegates property. I would think there's a better way to do this (I'm new to programming) but this is the best soultion I've come up with so far. Will update with sample code soon.